# dbmetal visual metal error:"magma string must not be empty"

Tags: .net, mysql, linq

I am just trying to generate the classes for **linq** to **mysql** with **dbmetal / visual metal** and keep running into the error:

```
"magma string must not be empty"...
```

I've googled, I've recompiled locally, checked the references etc. And I don't really want to start debugging this... anybody had the same issue before or knows of another way to generate those classes?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, believe it or not, it was caused by field names in the table ending with an underscore (_)... just for future reference, might save somebody else many hours...